# Table of Chebyshev psi function

Tags: function-construction, number-theory

This should be easy, but for some reason I'm struggling. The Chebyshev psi function is given as the sum from `0` to `x` of the von Mangoldt function `MangoldtLambda[x]`. I want to tabulate it. Ideally, I'd like to express the function using `Sum`, but I can't find the right form. This doesn't work:

```
TableForm[
 Table[With[{k = 10}, Sum[N[MangoldtLambda[x], 5], {x, 0, k}]], 
 {x, 0, 10}]]
```

This produces a series that makes no sense at all:

```
TableForm[
 Table[With[{k = 10}, Sum[N[MangoldtLambda[x], 5], {k, 0, x}]], 
 {x, 0, 10}]]
```

`Accumulate` doesn't work either:

```
TableForm[Table[Accumulate[N[MangoldtLambda[x], 5]], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

Clearly I'm suffering from a failure of imagination, but I'd appreciate help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There seems to be a duplicate use of the symbol `x` in your formulas.

```
ChebyshevPsi[x_] := Sum[MangoldtLambda[y], {y, x}]
Table[ChebyshevPsi[x], {x, 10}]
```

> {0, Log[2], Log[2] + Log[3], 2 Log[2] + Log[3], 
>    2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5], 2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5], 
>    2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + 2 Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + 2 Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7]}

You can also directly construct a list of these with `Accumulate`:

```
Accumulate@Array[MangoldtLambda, 10]
```

> {0, Log[2], Log[2] + Log[3], 2 Log[2] + Log[3], 
>    2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5], 2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5], 
>    2 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + 2 Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7], 
>    3 Log[2] + 2 Log[3] + Log[5] + Log[7]}

Plot the deviation of the Chebyshev $\psi$ function from $x$:

```
ListLinePlot[MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #1 - #2[[1]]} &, 
  Accumulate@Array[MangoldtLambda, 1000]], Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {x, ψ[x] - x}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'll tick this when it lets me! Appreciated.